# Problem with the density of the compound distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

My problem is to calculate $E[\max(S-5000, 0)]$ where 
$$S = \sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i,$$ 
$N$ is a random variable with geometric distribution, parametrized as follows:
$$P(N=n) = \frac{\beta^n}{(1+\beta)^{n+1}}, ~~~~~ n=\{0,1,2, ...\}$$
and ${X_1, X_2...}$ are all independent and exponentially distibuted with density:
$$f_X(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}.$$

I came up with an idea that I can find the density function of $S$ which is (according to my knowledge):
$$f_S(s) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_{X_1 + X_2 + ... +X_n}(s) \cdot P(N=n).$$

However, I encountered a problem - $N$ may have values $\{0,1,2,...\}$ (natural numbers WITH zero) but I can't calculate the density of the sum of zero random variables (the number of random variables to be sumed is zero when $n=0$).

Is it possible to calculate such density? It is there any other way to calculate $E[\max(S-5000, 0)]$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald's_equation Note that your question about $N=0$ is basically answered by the convention for the empty sum: when $N=0$ you have $S=0$. Wald's equation is consistent with this convention.

Comment: Though Wald's equation itself won't actually help you with the maximum part of the problem, hmm...

Comment: But if I consider that $f_S(s) = 0$ for $n=0$ and calculate the rest of the series and after that I calculate the integral
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}f_S(s)ds$$
it turns out that it doesn't equal 1...

Comment: Ah, I managed to write $1-\beta$ instead of $1+\beta$. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

First note that the sum of $n$ i.i.d. exponential random variables has an Erlang distribution, that is, for any $n\geqslant1$, the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ has probability density

$$\frac{(\lambda t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\lambda e^{-\lambda t}\mathsf 1_{(0,\infty)}(t).  $$
([How sum of exponential variables is a gamma variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1809607/how-sum-of-exponential-variables-is-a-gamma-variable/1809648#1809648)) It follows then that the distribution of $S$ is given by $\nu_S = \nu_S^d + \nu_S^c$, where for each Borel set $B$, $$\nu_S^d(B)  =\mu(B\cap\{0\})\mathbb P(N=0)   $$ where $\mu$ is counting measure, and $$\nu_S^c(B)=\int_B f_S\ \mathsf d\lambda$$
where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure. We compute $$\nu_S^d(B) =\mu(B\cap\{0\})(1+\beta)^{-1}  $$ and
\begin{align}
f_S(t) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_{S\mid N=n}(t)\mathbb P(N=n)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(\lambda t)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\lambda e^{-\lambda t}\frac{\beta^n}{(1+\beta)^{n+1}}\\
&= \frac{\beta \lambda e^{-\lambda t}}{(1+\beta)^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(\frac{\beta\lambda t}{1+\beta}\right)^n}{n!}\\
&=\frac{\beta\lambda}{(1+\beta)^2} \exp\left(-\frac{\lambda t}{1+\beta}\right)\mathsf 1_{(0,\infty)}(t).
\end{align}
It follows that 
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[(S-5000)^+] &= \int_{5000}^\infty (t-5000)\frac{\beta\lambda}{(1+\beta)^2} e^{-\frac{\lambda t}{1+\beta}}\ \mathsf dt\\
&= \frac\beta\lambda \exp\left(-\frac{5000\beta\lambda}{1+\beta}\right).
\end{align}

Comment: That is exactly the form of $f_S(t)$ that I managed to derive on my own. But notice that it is not a valid probability density function, since
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\beta\lambda}{(1+\beta)^2} \exp\left(-\frac{\lambda t}{1+\beta}\right) dt = \\
\frac{\beta}{1+\beta} \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda}{1+\beta} \exp\left(-\frac{\lambda t}{1+\beta}\right) dt = \\
= \frac{\beta}{1+\beta}
$$
I used the fact that $f(t) = \frac{\lambda}{1+\beta} \exp\left(-\frac{\lambda t}{1+\beta}\right)$ is the density of exponential distribution, so it's integral from $0$ to $\infty$ equals 1.

Comment: @Jerry You are forgetting to add the probability that $S=0$.